# CLLocation distanceFromLocation: returns -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocation

I have a function that finds the nearest `store` to the user location and sort the `allStores` array from the closest to the furthest.
After that it takes takes the stores on indexes 0-19 (20 closets stores to the user's location) and adds it to `twentyClosestStores` array.

The problem is: when I try to measure the ditance between `location1` to `location2` using `distanceFromLocation:` method, it returns `-1` and I can't understand why.

My code:

```
-(void)sortClosestStores
{
    [self.allStores sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        CLLocation *location1=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:((Store*)obj1).geoPoint.latitude longitude:((Store*)obj1).geoPoint.longitude];
        CLLocation *location2=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:((Store*)obj2).geoPoint.latitude longitude:((Store*)obj2).geoPoint.longitude];

        float dist1 =[location1 distanceFromLocation:self.locationManager.location]; //Returns -1
        float dist2 = [location2 distanceFromLocation:self.locationManager.location]; //Returns -1
    if (dist1 == dist2) {
        return NSOrderedSame; //Being called because both dist1 and dist 2' value is -1
    }
    else if (dist1 < dist2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];

    if (self.twentyClosestStores==nil) {
        self.twentyClosestStores=[NSMutableArray array];
    }
    self.twentyClosestStores=[NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        [self.twentyClosestStores addObject:[self.allStores objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea why it's not working properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the enum for `NSComparisonResult`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSComparisonResult) {NSOrderedAscending = -1L, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending};
```

-1 used for `NSOrderedAscending`

and you can sort your array using

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];

return [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```